# use while with drop down list to update active data on mysql database

Tags: php

```
(i have drop down list with two options with values),    

> >   <select  name="status"  id="statue"><option value="0"><option 
      value="1"></select>i use select tag    
> > 
> >
```

- with while As it is displayed in code below , these two options 
             Considered

  > > ```
  > > active for status, 0=not active,1=active , and i have two column     
  > >     name 
  > >   active and column name email on mysql database , my problem when 
  > >     select 
  > >   option value =1, the active column on mysql database update to
  > >   1 for all rows on active column , and i want to update active for
  > >   selected value that i choose and not for all rows on active column 
  > >
  > > <?php 
  > >    $qur=mysql_query("select * from sale");
  > >    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qur))  
  > >
  > >    /*  here using loop to Retrieval data from database with select
  > >        to   
  > >            make active 
  > >    */ and change value from 0 to 1 for only selected value and not for all
  > >
  > >
  > >    {
  > >    ?>
  > >    <tr>
  > >    <td><select name="status[]" id="status" ><option
  > >    selected>.....</option><option value="0">not active</option><option
  > >    value="1">active</option></select></td>
  > >    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['active'];?></td>
  > >    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
  > >    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
  > >    </tr>
  > >    <?php } ?>
  > >    </table>
  > >    <input type="submit" name="chk" value="Get Selected Values" />
  > >    <?php
  > >      if(isset($_POST['chk']))
  > >       {
  > >
  > >         foreach ($_POST['status'] as $select)
  > >        {
  > >           echo "You have selected :" .$select; // Displaying Selected  
  > >            Value
  > >           $sqlr=mysql_query("UPDATE sale SET active='$select'  WHERE 
  > >           id='".$row['id']."';");
  > >        }
  > >       } 
  > >    ?>
  > > ```
  > >
  > > when press on submit then return all values  0  OR  1  i want when
  > >     press on submit then just active only the selected item and update
  > >     value on database

Comment: You should avoid use `mysql_*`, it will be removed in the future updates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the WHERE clause in your query, it's a SQL statement problem, you have to tell SQL what row you want to modify, otherwise it will modify all rows. Try this:

```
 $sqlr=mysql_query("UPDATE sale SET active='".$select."' WHERE id = ".$row['id']." ;");
```

Change 'id' if needed to match the primary key field in your table, assuming that $row['id'] is the PK value of that row and $select is the value to set in the 'active' field.

Edit:
In case you are using active as a VARCHAR variable need to put the single quote, otherwise dont use the single quote. Are you sure the field ID is the PK and the variable $row['id'] is populated with the actual row id you want to change?

Comment: i did it but same problem >>if just make for example >> echo "You have selected :" .$select; // Displaying Selected Value// for example : it wil print 0,0,1 it will show correct value but when   $sqlr=mysql_query("UPDATE sale SET active='$select' WHERE id = $row['id'] ;");  nothing happen when with values update on mysql database

Comment: i did change that you suggest but no diffrent $sqlr=mysql_query("UPDATE sale SET active='$select' WHERE id = $row['id'] ;");

Comment: I have updated again the sentence in my post. In case you are using active as a VARCHAR variable need to put the single quote, otherwise dont use the single quote. Are you sure the field ID is the PK and the variable $row['id'] is populated with the actual row id you want to change?

Comment: i make sure for all notes you suggest but it's not work  , i  modify Post, i wish some one understand what i want

Answer (score -1):

you don't refer to any dataset.

```
$sqlr=mysql_query("UPDATE sale SET active='$select' WHERE [...]");
```